# How to overload operator for a set of sets of object

Tags: c++, set, overloading

I need to know how to overload the operator `=` `!=` and `<` so I could work with `set<set<object> >`

I have my class:

```
class pr{
private:
    set<set<e> > pr_;
public:
    pr();
    ~pr();
    void set_pr(set<e> a);
    pr& operator=(const pr& a) const;
    bool operator!=(const pr& a) const;
    bool operator<(const pr& a) const;
};
```

So if I have a set like this: `{{1,2,3},{4,5}}` where the numbers are objects.

I would like to do operations with the sets in other class like this:

```
void otherclass::myfunction(){

    pr prt; //I create the objects
    pr prt_old;

    set<e> C1; //I create the subset and fill
    set<e> C2;
     //C1 and C2 filled here    

    prt.set_pr(C1); //Insert the set<e> into set<set<e>>
    prt.set_pr(C2); //It will fail because i dont know how to compare set<e> < <set<e>

    while(prt != prt_old){
        prt_old = prt ;
        prt = create(prt_old);
    }
    //...
```

I tried to overload doing this:

```
 pr& pr::operator=(const pr& a) const{
   this->clear();

   for(set<set<e> >::iterator it =a.begin();it!=a.end();it++){
       for(set<e>::iterator j = it->begin(); j != it->end();j++){
           this->set_pr(*j);
       }
   }

   return *this;
}

bool pr::operator!=(const pr& a) const{
    if(this->size() != a.size()){
        return 1;
    } 

    //Now i don't know how to continue for check if for example
    // i had {{1,2},{3,4}} and {{1},{2}}
    //this two set have same size but they are differnt
    //How could i just iterate through the two sets at same time
    // and check if subset have too same size or if the objects inside the subset are equal

    //Also i need the operator < to insert a set<e> into a set<set<e> > but how??
//Note: class 'e' has already defined the "operator<" for when I insert objects in the set<e>
//And i order them by a function that return an integrer
```

Comment: I see no need to define a custom `operator=`, the default one should have no issues. `std::set` has its own, perfectly-working comparison operators, so all your comparison operators should do is invoke them. That's it.

Comment: You can see the error here: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘pr’ and ‘pr’)
         while(prt != prt_old){

Comment: To test if two sets are identical, you first test that their size is equal, and then iterate over each member of the first set, and test if it exists in the second set.

Answer (score 1):

To test if one set is contained in the other, you iterate over each member of the first set, and test if it exists in the second set.

```
    bool operator<(const pr& a) const {
        for (auto _set : _data) {
            if (a._data.find(_set) == a._data.end())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

To test if two sets are identical, you test their size is equal, and that one is contained in the other

```
    bool operator==(const pr& a) const {
        return _data.size() == a._data.size() && *this < a;
    }
```

But notice that there is no need to define an `operator==`, because the default one defined by `std::set` is fine.

Here is a full functioning program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

template <class e>
class pr {
private:
    set<set<e> > _data;
public:
    void insert(set<e> a) { _data.insert(a); }
    bool operator==(const pr& a) const {
        return _data.size() == a._data.size() && *this < a;
    }
    bool operator!=(const pr& a) const { return !(*this == a); }
    bool operator<(const pr& a) const {
        for (auto _set : _data) {
            if (a._data.find(_set) == a._data.end())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    pr<int> a,b,c;

    a.insert(set<int>({ 1 }));
    b.insert(set<int>({ 1 }));
    b.insert(set<int>({ 1, 2 }));
    c.insert(set<int>({ 1, 2 }));
    c.insert(set<int>({ 1 }));

    std::cout << ((a<b) ? "a<b\n" : "NOT a<b\n");
    std::cout << ((b<a) ? "b<a\n" : "NOT b<a\n");
    std::cout << ((a==c) ? "a==c\n" : "NOT a==c\n");
    std::cout << ((b==c) ? "b==c\n" : "NOT b==c\n");
    std::cout << ((a==b) ? "a==b\n" : "NOT a==b\n");
    return 0;
}
```